# Spacing between words using \break

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I get excessive word spacing at the bottom lines of paragraphs ending with `\break`.

I tried to add `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}`, `\raggedbottom`, loading `ragged2e` and loading `microtype`. Nothing seemed to work...

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
```

Anybody can help me with this?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Why are you using `\break`? You should leave an empty line between paragraphs, not use `\break`. `\break` doesn't create a paragraph break, as the name may suggest. Rather, it says to TeX that that point is a a place where a _line_ break will look good, so TeX forces a line break there and adds the necessary inter-word spacing to justify the text.

Comment: I am using \\ to break a line, \break to divide paragraphs, since it provides some spacing between them

Comment: No, ``\\`` shouldn't be used either. `\break` does a _line_ break, but does not end a paragraph. Leave an empty line between each paragraph and it will look better. If you want to change the spacing between paragraphs you can tweak the `\parskip`. For example, `\parskip = 1cm \relax` will leave plenty of space between paragraphs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the issue is not shown in the posted code, but has been solved in comments.